# Twincat 3: How to convert 4 HEX array to Float?

Tags: plc, twincat

we are receiving (via UDP datagram) a float value codified by 4 bytes hex array.

We need to convert from 4 hex bytes to a float.

```
udp_data[0] = 'BE';
udp_data[1] = '7A';
udp_data[2] = 'E0';
udp_data[3] = 'F4';
```

In the given example, the correct equivalence, after transformation, udp_data is equivalent to -0.24499:

What is the optimal conversion in Twincat 3 PLC? maybe some library? We need to perform 52 transformation at once of this type.

I attached an example with an example taken from an online calculator:

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a UNION type, which will at the same address hold a byte array (like the one you get from your UDP communication) and the real var which you want to convert to.
When you change the byte array, the real automatically reflects it. The conversion works the other way around also, in fact.

```
TYPE U_Convert :  
UNION  
    arrUDP_Data: ARRAY [0 .. 3] OF BYTE; // Array must start with LSB  
    rReal : REAL;  
END_UNION  
END_TYPE
```

In MAIN you can declare the following var.

```
VAR
    uConvert: U_Convert;
    fValue : REAL;
END_VAR
```

And in the body of MAIN, update the byte array to requested values.

```
// Here we update the byte array
uConvert.arrUDP_Data[0] := 16#F4; // LSB
uConvert.arrUDP_Data[1] := 16#E0;
uConvert.arrUDP_Data[2] := 16#7A;
uConvert.arrUDP_Data[3] := 16#BE; // MSB

// Here we 'use' the converted value
fValue := uConvert.rReal;
```

Comment: +1 for this. This is the most elegant way for conversion, The only problem is that you have to re-order those bytes in the array before this works (if the data comes from a other source, as I suppose it does). A simple helper function will do that, just write a function that changes array order.

Comment: +1 for this from me as well, this is indeed a more elegant solution than the one I suggested. An excellent use of unions!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have an array of bytes.
Header (put this in own function block if you want):

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    aByteArray : ARRAY[1..4] OF BYTE := [16#F4, 16#E0, 16#7A, 16#BE];
    pt : POINTER TO REAL;
    fRealValue : REAL;
END_VAR
```

Body:

```
pt := ADR(aByteArray);
fRealValue := pt^;
```

Will give you the desired result:

[image]